# How to compile dumpsys as an standalone application with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, dumpsys

I would like to compile dumpsys as an standalone application using Android NDK. However, when I enter the command `ndk-build` I encounter the following error:

*fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory*

Is it at all possible to compile dumpsys as an standalone app?

The source code and Android.mk file can be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-mr1-release/cmds/dumpsys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utils/Log.h isn't part of the NDK.

The AOSP sources aren't meant to be used with ndk-build.

You can compile dumpsys in-tree by following the instructions on how to setup an AOSP build and by calling `mm` from its sources directory (so you will not have to build the whole AOSP).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem is that I get this final output: **nothing to be done for _myapp_** even if I touch the directory before running `mm`.